# How to get the frame or bounds of the UIButtom was set on the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I can't get the frame or bounds of the `UIButtom` which was set on the storyboard.as you see on the picture below,the console just return 0. So how to get the frame or bounds by coding?

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your the Storyboard?

Comment: Try to print frame size, not position

Comment: Exactly what @rkyr said. You may be printing button's position which are in (0,0) position in your storyboard.

Comment: Did you connect the IBOutlet for the Label ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are logging this frame just too early, when the view is not laid out yet. Try to put your code in `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in your storyboard?

Comment: Thank you everybody.And I found the solution to this issue,as what @psci said,is put the code in viewWillAppear:method,because I used Autolayout on the StoryBoard.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect f2 = yourButton.frame;
NSLog(@"x origin: %f\n", f2.origin.x);
NSLog(@"y origin: %f\n", f2.origin.y);
NSLog(@"height: %f\n", f2.size.height);
NSLog(@"width: %f\n", f2.size.width);
```

dont forget to set IBOutlet.

Comment: You can replace this five lines with one: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(yourButton.frame));`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"x origin: %f", Button.frame.origin.x);
NSLog(@"y origin: %f", Button.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"height: %f", Button.bounds.size.height);
NSLog(@"width: %f", Button.bounds.size.width);
```

You need to set the IBoulet of the button and then you access the properties of it directly.

Answer (score 0):

First set IBoutlet of your button which is in storyboard.

Then follow steps.

```
CGRect btnFrame = yourButton.frame;

NSLog(@"My Button frame :%@",btnFrame);
```

Or you can directly using with,

```
NSLog(@"My Button frame :%@",self.yourButton.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think button object could be nil while logging frame. Can you try to log in ViewDidLoad methods

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLog(@"Button frame :%@",self.userPwdView.frame);
  }